# RESTful way of transmitting a single request containing multiple jobs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest

My browser based application requires an offline mode where jobs acting upon the same type of resource but of different operational types will be queued for later processing.

At that point, rather than performing potentially dozens of XHR requests, I'd like to package these jobs together into a single request in order to keep things quick and executed in the correct order. In its simplest form, it might look something like this (sorry for the pseudocode):

```
Request: POST /assets
Payload: [{"transaction": "create", "codes": [12345, 23456, 34567]}, {"transaction": "delete", "codes": [45678, 56789, 67890]}, ...]
```

... where the server-side would then decode the payload and turn it into separate jobs, returning a response informing the client of successes and failures.

Is this a sound approach? Or, are there any apparent downsides? Is there a more RESTful alternative?

Comment: As far as the definition of REST goes, you would POST to create, DELETE to delete, PATCH to edit etc, and combining these into one POST request is fundamentally incorrect. That's not to say that you couldn't do it though. Is there any problem with having dozens of requests that are done like this? From looking at your requests, they probably wouldn't require a huge amount of resource to handle, even in larger numbers...

Comment: Perhaps not. I just figured that since I need them to execute in order, all of the round-tripping required might add up. I guess it couldn't be too bad on the user unless they have an absolutely terrible network connection, and it certainly would be easier for me to implement on the client side.

Comment: It probably depends how correct you want to be with your RESTful approach, you could keep pushing new requests into an array and eventually send it off with request types listed in them as a single request method, it won't be REST correct though. Also might open you up to client side fiddling...?

Comment: I will pursue the REST correct approach, test it under constraints, and probably deploy it that way. If latency is a problem for users, I may then address it the other way at a later point. Thanks for the helpful feedback.